# set attribute to required when radio is checked

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a select box "required" but only when my radio button is checked, Below is what I have but does not seem to be working.

```
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" />

  <select name="selectbox" id="selectbox">
  <option value="1"> 1 </option>
  <option value="2"> 2 </option>
  <option value="3"> 3 </option>
  </select>
```

and the code

```
  function radiocheck(){
      if($('#radio').is(':checked')){
      $('#selectbox').prop('required',true);
      }}
```

Comment: How do you call radiocheck() if at all?

Comment: aren't you missing closing paranthesis `if($('#radio').is(':checked'))`

Comment: okay, you edited now, so it was a typo

Comment: Yea sorry, i'm just typing an example of what I want to achieve. set the property of the select to required only when the radio is checked. Just not sure what I am missing.

Comment: You're missing whatever calls `radiocheck`. Try `$('#radio').on('change', radiocheck);`...

Comment: You'll also want to remove the additional `}` at the end of `radiocheck`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lmpf3arh/3/ and edit to answer above by Ted

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" />

  <select name="selectbox" id="selectbox" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1"> 1 </option>
  <option value="2"> 2 </option>
  <option value="3"> 3 </option>
  </select>
```

and script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#radio').change(function(e){
        if($('#radio').is(':checked')){
            $('#selectbox').prop('disabled',false);
            $('#selectbox').prop('required',true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This works, but the idea behind the 'required' is once the user selects the radio button, they have to chose an option from the box. I believe setting it to required would work if the default option was blank.

Comment: thats no prob, you can add that too in condition as `$('#selectbox').prop('required',true);`, editing the answer

Comment: but i think you will need 1st option as this `<option value="">Please select</option>`

Comment: Up-vote for finishing out the solution for the OP :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#radio').change(function(e){
        if($('#radio').is(':checked')){
            $('#selectbox').prop('required',true);
        }
    });
});
```

[**See it in action here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmpf3arh/)

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. I guess the other question is how to get the default value for the select box to be blank.  <option value ="" select disabled> ?

Comment: This is possible that he did not call the function, but what I am thinking is, it is a select with 3 simple options, one is anyway going to remain selected, is there something we are missing to understand?

Comment: okay I got your problem, you want to enable and disable select list not required

Answer (score 1):

Update the state when the radio is selected:

http://codepen.io/himedlooff/pen/bdpdOo

```
$('#radio').on('change', function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#selectbox').prop('required', 'required');
  } else {
    $('#selectbox').removeAttr('required');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set it back to `false` if the radio becomes unselected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#radio').change(function(e){
        var req = false;
        if($('#radio').is(':checked')){
            req = true;
        } 
        $('#selectbox').prop('required',req);
    });
});
```